# Querying a Sequelize model fields to overlap a date interval

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

How can I execute the following query using Sequelize model `SomeTable` and `.findAll` method:

```
SELECT * from SomeTable WHERE (dateCol1, dateCol2) OVERLAPS ('2001-10-30', '2002-10-30')
```

`dateCol1` and  `dateCol2` are `DATE` columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with `sequelize.literal` :

```
where : {
    sequelize.literal('(dateCol1, dateCol2) OVERLAPS ('2001-10-30', '2002-10-30')')
}
```

Comment: Now I use the following syntax: 
`sequelize.literal(\`(dateCol1, dateCol2) OVERLAPS (${sequelize.escape(start)}, ${sequelize.escape(finish)})\`)`

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it works! I will wait a little for the other answers, may be it is possible to achieve this using `[Op.overlap]` or `$overlap` syntax? If it is not possible - I will accept your answer.

Comment: @EugeneMala, if it was single column on left side it was possible, but its 2 columns so it might not be possible as long as i know. still ew can wait.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue except the type of `dateCol1 dateCol2` were `Timestamp with timezone` instead of DATEONLY.
This is what i tried and it fixed my issue...

```
{
where: {
    [Op.all]: Sequelize.literal(`(dateCol1, dateCol2) OVERLAPS (to_timestamp(${new Date(date1).getTime() / 1000}),
            to_timestamp(${new Date(date2).getTime() / 1000}))`),
}}
```